# how could I use group regexp in IDEA?

Tags: regex, intellij-idea

Consider I have wrote some codes like :

```
private String Name;
private String Age;
private String Grader;
...
```

I would like to change Name,Age,Grader to the lowercase using the regex replace in IDEA, 
so I wrote,  `(private\s+String\s+)([A-Z])(\w+;)`  -> `\1\l\2\3` , but IDEA didnot support the \1 the find the group matching ,but it works fine in sublime text, is there anyway to solve this?

Comment: try `$1` instead of `\1`

Comment: You are right ,and how to change it to lower case, `\l` doesnot work

Comment: `\l$1` and `\L$1` doesnot work, but `$1` work

Answer (score 1):

#### Answer for versions IntelliJ 15 and newer

New versions IntelliJ offer this functionality:
(from the official IntelliJ [Regular Expression Syntax Reference](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/regular-expression-syntax-reference.html))

```
\l
```

Changes the case of the next character to the lower case.

```
\u
```

Changes the case of the next character to the upper case.

```
\L
```

Changes the case of all the subsequent characters up to \E to the lower case.

```
\U
```

Changes the case of all the subsequent characters up to \E to the upper case.

Therefore \L$1\E should work now.

#### Answer for versions older than IntelliJ 15

IntelliJ doesn't offer an option to change the case in the replacement String.

But you can use Structural Search And Replace in IntelliJ (Ctrl+Shift+M).

Search template:

```
private String $upper$;
```

Replacement template:

```
private String $lower$;
```

You also have to "Edit variables..."

upper -> Text constraints:

```
[A-Z]\w+
```

lower -> Script constaints:

```
String text = upper.getText()
text[0].toLowerCase() + text.substring(1)
```

The only diffrence in the result compared to your description should be, that afterwards you will have single spaces only between the words.